# "To" field missing when viewing received emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I have outlook 2003 on Vista. Just recently, when viewing an email (by opening it), the "from" field is shown along with the date received, but there is no "to" or "cc" fields shown. Any ideas how to turn these back one or why they disappeared?

Just to be clear, these fields are shown when viewing in the preview pane, but they not shown when viewing the email in a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope that you have installed the latest Microsoft Office 2003 service pack SP3.

You can also try to [Create a New Outlook Profile](http://www.outlook-tips.net/howto/profile.htm), on the assumption that your own profile is corrupted.

Question: What happens when you do two times View / Message Header (the first will hide the headers and the second will show them again) ?